# PHP preg_replace replacing numbers along with special chars

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, php-5.3

I have the following PHP code to remove special characters from a variable;

```
<?php
$name = "my%^$@#name8";
$patterns = array( '/\s+/' => '_', '/&/' => 'and', '/[^[:alpha:]]+/' => '_');
$name2 = preg_replace(array_keys($patterns), array_values($patterns), trim($name));
echo $name2;
?>
```

But, along with special chars, numbers also are getting replaced with underscores`_`. I want to include numbers in the result. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your third pattern, `/[^[:alpha:]]+/` is replacing everything that's not a letter with an underscore.  So add numbers to it, like `/[^[:alpha:]0-9]+/`

Answer (score 2):

Replace `'/[^[:alpha:]]+/'` with `'/[^[:alpha:][:digit:]]+/'`.  The original is replacing anything that's not an alphabetic character.  Adding [:digit:] means it will replace anything that's not a letter or a number, so your numbers will be preserved as well.